# Copy decimal format

Tags: c#

I have a third party API that provides numbers such as `123.456`, `12.345`, `1.23`. How to I extract the formatting from that number and apply it to my own number?

For example, the input I get is `123.465`, and my number is `9999.99999`; I want my number to be formatted like `999.999`.

Another example is, if the format is `12.3`, and my number is `9.9999`, the result should be `99.9`.

Comment: So you are asking how to round a number to a specific number of decimals?

Comment: Simplified version `YES`. But the rounding must happen based on incoming value which is not static.

Comment: so does your API provide the numbers as strings? and you want to find the format inside this string? and show you own values in the same format?

Comment: @MongZhu You are absolutely right :)

Comment: so you basically need the amount of decimals am I right? or can you receive also numbers with leading zeros ?=! like `0023.24500` ?

Comment: So if you receive `230.345` you expect this format: `###.###` and display every other value with this format, e.g. `123456.78` becomes `123.45678`?

Comment: @PaulF Bit of both really, I'm doing databinding to the property. But  guess as long as I have correct format and correct decimal this isnt a problem to convert between `string` and `int`.

@MongZhu Both sir.

Comment: " convert between string and int" ? now I am confused... decimals or not ?=!

Comment: @FCin Correct!!! But `123456.78` will then become `123.456`

Comment: @MongZhu Sorry that part wasn't for you. But but yes lets say decimal.

Comment: Am I the only one that finds this conversation quite confusing...

Comment: @envyM6 The question was put on hold but, check this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/GcyAN4

Move the position of the dot on the "number" variable, and sorry it's a bit short and lazy, just a quick hack to see if I got the question right.

Comment: As I cannot put an answer, try this:            
`string number = "23234.55235";
 int length = number.Substring(number.IndexOf(".")).Length -1;
 decimal m = 12.878999m;
 decimal newVal = Decimal.Round(m, length);`

Comment: @L.Guthardt yeah.  i was hoping the comments would clarify the question, but seeing as they're just becoming more confusing and muddled, I finally decided it was time to cast my close vote.

Comment: @E.Hoxha No you are on right track. Apologies if I was lazy at explaining. But I want the number to trim to exact same decimal places too. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Amy I agree with the close vote, but it's quite sad though. I´d like to help him out, but explaining what you have in mind and you want to achieve to someone that can't look straight into your head is sometimes quite messy.

Comment: Hey guys. Combining @E.Hoxha and @Code Pope s answer `static string number = "23234.55235";
  static int length = number.Substring(number.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)).Length - 1;
  static decimal m = 12.87899999m;


  public static string GetResult(string input, int decimalIndex)
  {
   var ret = input.Replace(".", "");
   return ret.Insert(decimalIndex, ".");
  }

  Console.WriteLine(GetResult(m.ToString(), length));`

I think thats what I need.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @envyM6 I updated my solution. It's still a hack, but a better one now.
You should try to remove the try catch tho, do if checks. Hope that helps!

https://dotnetfiddle.net/GcyAN4

I tried your solution and I was getting the decimal point 1 point on the right and there was no limit on the amount of numbers after the decimal dot.

Comment: If you guys think the question is now clear enough to be re-opened, then by all means, vote to reopen.

Comment: @E.Hoxha seems thats producing correct result. Appreciated. But isn't that too much calculations ?

Comment: @Amy Lol I would you love to see this getting re-opened.

Comment: @envyM6 It has a few, but it's still pretty fast (plus that's why I said it's more of a hack :P). Also I've edited your question to clearly express your intent, at least I think I've gotten it right.

Comment: @E.Hoxha Fantastic. `APROVED!!`